# Post File to URL using java with authentication

Tags: java, file, upload, io

I tried the code below:

```
public class URLUploader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {

        URL url = new URL("http://77.203.65.164:6011");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        String name = "user";
                String password = "password";

                String authString = name + ":" + password;
                System.out.println("auth string: " + authString);
                byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
                String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
                System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);

        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

        writer.write("/var/www/html/kannel/javacode/13569595024298.xml");
        writer.flush();
        String line;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(line);
        }

        writer.close();
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

But I got the following error:

```
auth string: optiweb:optiweb
Base64 encoded auth string: b3B0aXdlYjpvcHRpd2Vi
    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: 77.203.65.164:6011
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1403)
    at URLUploader.main(URLUploader.java:32)
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting an authentication error? It seems like your just writing a file straight to the remote server, but you probably want to post it as form-encoded data. For starters, I'd suggest you use the jakarta [http client library](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

First, HTTP Response Code 500 is "Internal Server Error" and has nothing to do with authentication.

Second, the statement

```
writer.write("/var/www/html/kannel/javacode/13569595024298.xml");
```

just writes the file's full pathname to the server, not the actual file contents, without even a trailing newline.  This is certainly not what the server is expecting, and may be the cause of the 500 response.  The request you are building and sending may have other problems as well, but without a detailed API reference for whatever's on the other end of the connection, it will be hard to provide further help.

Comment: I have tried to write the file to a byte array but this does not work too, that datatype is write.write() expecting?